# Sublime Text 3 - Create tab autocomplete

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, sublimetext3, erb

I'm sorry if this has been answered but I just don't know how to look for it. Thanks for understanding.

I'm working in rails with sublime text and when working in .html.erb code I'd like an easy way to insert <% %> <%= %> easily instead of having to type everything. For example, if you type div.some and then hit tab, it will transform to < div class="some"> < /div>.

I'd like something similar, like this:

- If I type % then hit tab, it should transform to <% %>
- If I type %= then hit tab, it should transform to <%= %>

Any help will be apreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sublime Text is only a text editor. Use IDE instead. Such as [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/) and its [keyboard shortcuts](http://kbmode.com/windows/aptana-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: @ChetanDatta fortunately, Sublime has lots of features that other text editors don't, so this type of thing is easily possible, with snippets, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used this plugin to to this.

For examples:

```
ERB tags           | er | <% %>
print ERB tags     | pe | <%= %>
print ERB comment  | pc | <%# %>
```

https://github.com/matthewrobertson/ERB-Sublime-Snippets

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll check it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Sublime Text snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippets), take a look at the guide. For example, you can set an snippet for `'er'` that translates into `<% %>`

You can also try [Haml](http://haml.info/), it's more beautiful and easy to write than erb, there is also a Sublime Text package to migrate your `html.erb` to `.haml` files.

Sorry, but I can't post more than two links, you can search the package at Google or Sublime Text Package Manager

Comment: Great! Please mark the correct answer, so this is more useful for others